# exporting values to csv file from jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

we are running 100 threads at a time in jmeter for load testing purpose.we have to set the rampup as 0.1.we have done some coding using bean shell processor to copy the result to a csv file.but if we run only 97 out of 100 records are getting loaded.so this is the coding:

```
MasterConsumerID =vars.get("MasterConsumerID");
log.info(MasterConsumerID);
f = new FileOutputStream("D:/priya.csv",true);
p=new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print( MasterConsumerID);
f.close();
```

is there any option how we can save all the 100 records?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to Beanshell performance problems on high loads so consider switching to [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) (Sampler, Pre or Post Processor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language instead of Beanshell.

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for more detailed explanation, groovy engine installation instructions and scripting best practices.

---

There is an alternative way of writing JMeter Variables values into a file - you may append your `MasterConsumerID` variable value to .jtl results file using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property like:

1. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (it lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   sample_variables=MasterConsumerID
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Next time you run the test you'll see `MasterConsumerID` variable value in the last column of .jtl results file